# Which class relationship will it be [specific to C++]?

Tags: c++, class, uml, relationship

Which relation is this if a class constructor has a reference to another class in parameter list? Will it be an association, aggregation or composition?

```
class A
{
    public:
       void func()
       {
           ....
       }           
};

class B
{
  public:
     B(A& a)
     {
        a.func();
     }
};
```

Comment: The constructor doesn't really matter - member variables do. e.g. Does `B::B` need `A&` because it "has a[n]" `A`? Or does it just read `a.foo` and do something arbitrary, or maybe not even use `a` at all?

Answer (score 3):

> *"Will it be an association, aggregation or composition?"*

```
B(A& a) {
    a.func(); // <<<< «call» dependency
}
```

A constructor parameter in c++ will provide a weak association (in your case a «call» dependency) in UML. That it's a reference parameter doesn't matter in this case.

Aggregation or composition relationships need to be realized with class attributes.